# What is the set complement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $A = \{x \ |\  0 < x < 10\}$ (where the universal set is the set of positive real
numbers less than or equal to $20$), what is the complement of $A$?

I am thinking that it is the integers $11$ through $20$. If I am wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that the positive real numbers include all rational and irrational numbers, not just the integers.  For instance, $\frac{1}{2} \in A$ and $\pi \in A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U = \left(0,20\right], A = (0,10) \Rightarrow A^{c} = [10,20] = \{x: 10 \leq x \leq 20\}$.